# Syntax problem when checking for a file

Tags: php

This piece of code has previously worked but I have C&P it to a new place and for some reason, it now won't work!

```
        <?
        $user_image = '/images/users/' . $_SESSION['id'] . 'a.jpg';
        if (file_exists(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . $user_image))) 
        {
            echo '<img src="'.$user_image.'" alt="" />';
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo '<img src="/images/users/small.jpg" alt="" />';
        }
        ?>
```

As you can see, I am checking for a file, if exists, showing it, if not, showing a placeholder.

The $_SESSION['id'] variable does exist and is being used elsewhere within the script.

Any ideas what the problem is?

Thanks

Comment: Define "won't work". Does the conditional fail when you think it should succeed? Is the value of `$user_image` not what you expect? Is `__FILE__` not what you expect?

Comment: Well, what *is* the problem? The file doesn't exist? Try `echo realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . $user_image))` and see if it exists.

Comment: Check your file paths. If you copied somewhere else, it is very likely that paths don't match.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It fails and therefore shows the placeholder. But the file is definitely there!

Comment: @Luke: If it would be there, then `file_exists(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . $user_image))` would not return false. If there was something else wrong you would not event see the other image.

Comment: Luke, when you say "copied to a new place", what do you mean? A new directory, or a different server, or...?

Comment: @Felix Kling - the else statement goes into the same directory and shows that image.

Comment: @Rob - i moved the code to a new script which is in a different directory.

Comment: @Luke: Then what is the output of `echo realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . $user_image)`? Do you want to say that the function itself is broken?

Comment: @Felix - nothing happens at all with that echo statement. So nothing displays!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok lets put it simple:

You have your images at

```
/foo/bar/images/users/*.jpg
```

and your script was at

```
/foo/bar/script.php
```

before, which worked, because `realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . $user_image)` creates

```
/foo/bar/image/users/*.jpg
```

But now, when you e.g. moved your script to another directory on the same level (`/foo/baz/script.php`), the output of the previous command will be

```
 /foo/baz/image/users/*.jpg
```

and this path **does not** exist.

You said in your comment you moved the script to another directory. If you didn't move the images too, your script definitely fails.

---

Also note there is a difference in accessing the images via a URL (i.e. from the outside) or via a file path (i.e. from the inside). Your images will always be available via `www.yourdomain.com/images/users`, but if you move your PHP script into another directory, `dirname(__FILE__)` *has* to give you another value and thus the test *will fail*:

```
foo/
|
- baz/
| |
| - script.php <-absolut path: /foo/baz/images/users/...
|
- bar/ <- entry point of URL is always here
  |
  - script.php <- absolut path: /foo/bar/images/users/...
  - images/    
    |
    - users/
      |
      - *.jpg
```

**Update:**

If your script is *one level below* the images, a fix could be:

```
file_exists(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../' . $_SESSION['id'] . 'a.jpg'))
```

This will generate something like `/foo/images/users/v3/../12a.jpg`. `..` means going up a level.

Or going up several levels and using `$user_image`:

```
realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../..' . $user_image)
```

Comment: Yeah I understand. If I use    echo '<img src="/images/users/1a.jpg" alt="" />';
 it shows the image. So it's something to do with the syntax!

Comment: @Luke: Not the syntax. Your path construction is broken. It points to a wrong path. You need to fix this. But until now, you are the only one that knows the directory structure. E.g. a fix could be `dirname(__FILE__) . '../bar' . $user_image`.

Comment: Ok. My script is currently one level down from where the images are. I have images in the directory and also a directly called v3. Within v3 is the script I am trying to run. Maybe this can help solve this?